# Determining Prime Numbers Java

Tags: java

I am writing a program that takes as input an integer, and outputs a message whether the integer entered is prime or not. The algorithm I am using is as follows... **Require:** n>0, **Require:** isPrime <- true, **for** i=2 to sqrt(n) **do**, **if** n%i=0 **then** isPrime <- false **end if** and **end for** Then Print whether the number is Prime or not. Here is my code so far, the code is not working and I am not able to find the problem.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    System.out.println("Input a positive integer");
    n = kb.nextInt();

        while (n>0){
            boolean isPrime = true;
            for (int i =2; i <= n/2;i++){
                if(n % i == 0){
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isPrime = true){
                System.out.println("The integer, " + n + ", is a prime");
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("The integer, " + n + ", is not a prime");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could help, Thanks!

Comment: It's not working? In what way is it 'not working'? Please! Give us a clue!

Comment: Do you realize that `isPrime = true` is assignment and not comparison?

Comment: You can make this faster by omitting all even numbers except 2. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/

Comment: Just out of curiosity where are you calculating the square root of your input number? It seems like you are still going till n/2 to check for prime condition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem lies with this line:

```
if (isPrime = true){
```

You made an assignment, instead of comparing to `true`, so the statement is always `true`.

Use `==` to compare boolean values, or better yet, since `isPrime` is already a `boolean`:

```
if (isPrime){
```

Answer (score 1):

In the text you say the algorithm you intend to implement checks  integers up to the square root of `n` but your code is going all the way up to `n/2` (see the for loop).

The reason your current code isn't working is because `if (isPrime = true)` is an assignment operation and should be comparison `if (isPrime == true)` note the two equal signs.

Comment: I have a vage souvenir of my algebra lessons, but I think that's how it works