# How to factor a number and determine whether its a prime number

Tags: java

So i have this problem where when i factor a number, lets say 15, i have to display this: 15=3x5 but instead what i get is 3x5x5 and i have no clue of how to make it that so it only displays 3x5. And then another problem i have is to find whether the number i inputted is a prime number or not. Any way of fixing this? I just need that and the other stuff im gonna edit after that.

```
public class PrimeFactor 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        int d;
        int remainder=0;
        int count=2;
        int c=0;
        String s;
        System.out.println("Enter an integer to be factored:");
        a=input.nextInt();
        s="";
        d=a;
        while(a>1)
        {
            if(a>1)
            { 
                s="";
                while(a>1)
                {
                    remainder=a%count;
                    if (!(remainder>0))
                        while(remainder==0)
                        {
                            remainder=a%count;
                            if (remainder==0)
                            {    
                                a=a/count;
                                c=c+1;
                                s=s+count+"x";
                                if (a==1)
                                    s=s+count;
                            }
                            else
                                count++;
                        }
                    else 
                        count++;
                }
                if (a%count==0)
                {
                    System.out.println(d +"=" + s);
                    System.out.println(d+" is a prime number.");
                }
                else
                    System.out.println(d +"=" + s);
            }
        // TODO code application logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining Prime Numbers Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625793/determining-prime-numbers-java)

Comment: @ppaulojr: only partly, that one is about testing if it's a prime, this one also about factoring it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This determines if the number is prime or not the quickest way. Another method would be to use a `for loop` to determine the number of factors for the number and then say it's prime if it has more than two factors.

```
int num; // is the number being tested for if it's prime.
boolean isPrime = true;

for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) // only have to test until the square root of the number
{
    if (num%i == 0) // if the number is divisible by anything from 2 - the square root of the number
    {
        isPrime = false; // it is not prime
        break; // break out of the loop because it's not prime and no more testing needed
    }
}

if (isPrime) 
{
    System.out.println(num + " is a prime number.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println(num + " is a composite number.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are quite straight-forward methods you can use to factor a number and determine if it is a prime number:

```
public static int oneFactor(int i) {
    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0)
            return j;
    }
    return -1;
}

public static Integer[] primeFactors(int i) {
    List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    boolean cont = true;
    while (cont) {
        int f = oneFactor(i);
        if (i > 1 && f != -1) {
            i /= f;
            factors.add(f);
        } else
            factors.add(i);
        if (f == -1)
            cont = false;
    }

    return factors.toArray(new Integer[factors.size()]);
}

public static boolean isPrime(int i) {
    if (i == 2 || i == 3)
        return true;

    if (i < 2 || i % 2 == 0)
        return false;

    for (int j = 3, end = (int) Math.sqrt(i); j <= end; j += 2) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am sure one can use faster algorithms, but those would be at the cost of simplicity, and it doesn't seem like you need high speed methods.
They all operate on ints, but its easy to change them to work with longs.
If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

You are not constructing the factorization string quite right:

- When you find that 3 divides a=15 you set s to `3x` and set `a` to the quotient, so `a=5`
- When you find that 5 divides a=5 you append `5x` to `s`, so now `s` is `3x5x`. Then you set `a` to the quotient, which is 1. Since the quotient is now `1`, you append 5 again, so now you get `3x5x5`.

What you'll want to do is append only `5` when `a=1`, not `5x5`. You have to change this:

```
s=s+count+"x";
if (a==1)
    s=s+count;
```

to this:

```
if (a==1) {
    s=s+count;
} else {
    s=s+count+"x";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying like this:-

```
for(int i = input-1; i > 0; i--) {
    if((input % i) == 0) {
            if(i == 1)
                System.out.println("Number is a prime");
            else
                System.out.println("Number is not a prime");
            break;
    }       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to write a loop which loops through numbers 1 to (Inputted Number). And if you found a factor, you print it and divide the input by the factor. (And test if it can be divided again by the same number), else then skip to the next number.

Keep doing this until your input divides down to 1.

**This program will break the number down to prime factors:**

```
public class Factor {
    public static void main() {
        //Declares Variables
        int factor = 15;
        int i = 2;

        System.out.println("Listing Factors:\n");
        while (factor>1) {
            //Tests if 'i' is a factor of 'factor' 
            if (factor%i == 0) {
                //Prints out and divides factor
                System.out.println(i);
                factor = factor/i;
            } else {
                //Skips to next Number
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Listing Factors:

3
5
```